# Prove that $2\pi$ periodic function, $f$, with Fourier coefficients equal zero if $n$ is odd

Tags: fourier-series

Let $f$ be a continuous, $2\pi$-periodic function and
suppose that its Fourier coefficients, $a_n$ and $b_n$, equal $0$ when $n$ is odd, i.e.,
\begin{equation}
\int_{-\pi}^\pi f(x)\cos (nx)\,dx=\int_{-\pi}^\pi f(x)\sin (nx)\,dx=0,\quad n \ne 2k.
\end{equation}

Is there a way to prove that $f$ is $\pi$-periodic?

Comment: Just write down the Fourier series. It will be of the type $ \sum a_{2n}\cos (2nx)+\sum a_{2n} \sin (2nx)$ .

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thanks. I now see that because $S_n(x)=S_n(x+\pi)$ then $\sigma_{n}(x)=\sigma_{n}(x+\pi)$ and because $f(x)=lim_{n \to \infty}\sigma_n(x)$ then $f$ is $\pi$-periodic